# ORA-00984: column not allowed here Oracle SQL 11g Create Error

Tags: sql, oracle

El error me aparece al intentar crear tablas en Oracle SQL 11g no se por que sucede ya intente cambiar de todo sin embargo no logro encontrar el problema.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE SPC_UL_box(
box_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
box_name VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL,
active BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
created DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
last_update DATE DEFAULT NULL,
deleted DATE DEFAULT NULL
);

Error report -
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL no acepta los nombres sin comillas: requieres especificar que es una cadena (interesante ya que esto no pasa en MySQL o MS SQL Server). Esto fue lo que me funcionó; por cierto tampoco tiene booleanos:

```
CREATE TABLE "SPC"."SPC_UL_BOX" 
(   "BOX_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"BOX_NAME" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ACTIVE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1, 
"CREATED" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
"LAST_UPDATED" DATE DEFAULT null, 
"DELETED" DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT "SPC_UL_BOX_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BOX_ID")
 );
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.